# Suppose that $X$ is a set of ordinals. Then there exists an ordinal $\beta\notin X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, ordinals

Does my attempt look fine or contain gaps? Thank you so much!

---

> Suppose that $X$ is a set of ordinals. Then there exists an ordinal $\beta\notin X$.

---

**My attempt:**

> Lemma: Let $X$ be a set of ordinals and $\alpha=\bigcup X$. Then $\alpha$ is an ordinal.

I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955841/let-x-be-a-set-of-ordinals-and-alpha-bigcup-x-then-alpha-is-an-ordinal).

---

Let $\alpha=\bigcup X$. It follows from Lemma that $\alpha$ is an ordinal.

Let $\beta=\alpha\bigcup\{\alpha\}$. It's easy to verify that $\beta$ is an ordinal and that $\alpha\in\beta$.

Finally, we prove that $\beta\notin X$.

Assume the contrary that $\beta\in X$. Then $\alpha\in\beta\in X$ and thus $\alpha\in\bigcup X=\alpha$. This is a contradiction.

Hence $\beta\notin X$.

Comment: Perfect${}{}{}{}$, well, you may want to state what it contradiction to in the last statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct like I said in a comment but here is a different way:

We know that $X$ is a set. Assume the contrary, $\forall \beta\in On(\beta\in X)$, then define $f:X\to On,f(a)=a$. It is clear that $f(X)=On$ which implies that the collection of all ordinals is a set. Contradiction

Comment: Thank you so much! I got your proof. It's quite sad to me that I have not been exposed to Class yet.

Comment: @LeAnhDung you mean "proper class", every set is a class ;)

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant: *proper class* ^^